# How to assure a single run of a method in a multi-process unicorn rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, heroku, locking

I've got a Rails web application that runs on Heroku in production on a multi-threaded unicorn server.

In my application is a method that can only be executed by max. one of these processes. If concurrent calls happen, they need to queue up.

What is the most secure way to do this?

What I already thought of was to use the environment:

```
def my_method
  sleep .1 while ENV['method_locked'] == 'locked'
  ENV['method_locked'] = 'locked'

  # Do my stuff

  ENV['method_locked'] = 'unlocked'
end
```

I've got two concerns about this:

- Is a mutated environment shared across multiple unicorn processes? And multiple dynos? And if not, is there a *fast* storage available that is?
- If the concurrency is high, is the time it takes to query and update the environment going to be a problem that still allows for concurrency?

The other solution I had in mind was to spawn a separate process to take care of this, either using a separate worker dyno or by somehow abusing another unicorn thread (although I don't know whether this is possible at all.)

My question is: is there an even nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutating `ENV` wouldn't work. You'd only change ENV for the current process, it will not affect other processes.

If I were you, I would probably use redis to handle my locks. Here's a gem that I would use: [redis-lock](https://github.com/PatrickTulskie/redis-lock).

If you don't know, redis is single-threaded and very fast. Ideal external memory for your case.

Comment: It's funny! I've stumbled upon redis many times, mostly by seeing it required by other stuff, so I know what it is. The funny thing is I never thought why it's so popular, as I couldn't think of a proper use case that could not be done otherwise with less of a hassle. Seems I've got my perfect use case here! Thanks a lot for your answer!